# How to add a number to variable within String.format?

Tags: java, loops, variables, operator-keyword

I want output like:

```
Dividend 1 : ...
Dividend 2 : ...
Dividend 3 : ...
```

Here is my code:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < dividendRates.length) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Dividend %d : ", i) + (income * dividendRates[i]) );
    i = i + 1;
}
```

But dividend number start with `0`.

The easy way is just create new variable like 'int e = 1;' and use it, but I want to use variable 'i' and have output start with `1`.

What should I do?

Comment: Replace `i` with `i + 1`? `String.format("Dividend %d : ", (i + 1))`

Comment: @Loftoff holy..... I feel like an Idiot........ thank you for your kindness..

Comment: As an aside, based on the snippet alone, I'd recommend using a for-loop instead of a while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code and I hope get the point:

```
int i = 1;
    while( (i-1) < dividendRates.length) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Dividend %d : ", i) + (income*dividendRates[i]) );
        i = i + 1;

    }
```